# Is it possible to dynamically create tests based on array elements using cucumber?

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

Is it possible to generate dynamically test scenarios for each element in array?

I've got two arrays with elements (each for an environment against which I run test suite), like that:

`devEnv = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4']`

`testEnv = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3']`

In dev env there are 4 link available, in test env only 3.

In protractor + jasmine you can get `it`s in a loop like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35114139/6331748

I'm using protractor + cucumber.

When I hardcode in feature file date like that:

```
Scenario Outline:
    Given I am on main page
    When I click "<linkToGo>" link
    Then I should be on "<linkToGo>" page

    Examples:
        |linkToGo |
        |link1    |
        |link2    |
        |link3    |
        |link4    |
```

The tests will pass for dev env - all 4 links will be clicked, but on test env there's not `link4`.

Any ideas how to solve case like that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create 2 different scenario with different **Tags**

1. @Dev

   Scenario Outline: To test Dev Enmv
   Given I am on main page
   When I click "" link
   Then I should be on "" page

   Examples:
       |linkToGo |
       |link1    |
       |link2    |
       |link3    |
       |link4    |
2. @Test

   Scenario Outline: To test Test envmt
   Given I am on main page
   When I click "" link
   Then I should be on "" page

   Examples:
       |linkToGo |
       |link1    |
       |link2    |
       |link3    |

Same Gherkin line is used with same SD.
Now depends on your need, pass the tag to Configuration file
Hope this will solve your problem.